# Sending SD commands from Android app

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

Is it possible to send SD (Secure Digital) commands from Android app to SD card ?
Commands are read SD card, write to SD card etc (CMD18, CMD24).

The constraint is the phone should NOT be a rooted phone.  With rooted phone we are able to send SD commands but not with unrooted phone. On attempting we get the error "permission denied".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No.  You should not be able to access the raw device when running as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. The SD card hardware is abstracted away and mounted as a directory in the filesystem. Why would you want to send raw commands to the SD card anyway? Why not just read and write files on it?

Comment: When i used the SD card apart from just read/write it is useful. Say I want to set password on SD card, which is a facility offered by SD card but at command level. I do NOT want an external application to secure SD card instead I want to use the SD firmware functionality.

Comment: If you need to interact with a specific hardware device, such as the SD card, you will need driver-level software. You get access to hardware devices such as GPS, cell radio, Bluetooth, and SD cards only through abstracted interfaces because they must be shared with all other applications on the device. That is one of the purposes of an OS in the first place. If you need security on an SD card, you must encrypt your data at the application level.