# Sending SD commands from Android app even for Rooted Phones

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

Is it possible to send SD commands from Android app to SD card ? Commands are read SD card, write to SD card etc (CMD18, CMD24).

Even for the rooted phones..

I think he is doing this in 
[Sending SD commands from Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625790/sending-sd-commands-from-android-app)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could do it only in rooted devices